# 4 digit number formatting in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

There is this requirement for my application where-in the user types a value in the text box field and parallely shown in a box below. BUT the problem is I want to have format something like this **1234-1234-1234** (including the dashes). Can that be possible. I've tried using the angular filters but seems to be not working.

Comment: You can use input mask plugin for easily do that

Comment: Which version of angular is this? also show the code that you tried so far?

Comment: Where is your attempt what already you have tried??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Angular 1.X, I would suggest you to create a directive for this which will give a better control on the element.

Try below

```js
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.directive('inputFormat', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="inputVal" placeholder="Enter a number" />',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('keyup', function() {
        var inputElm = elem.val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
        if (inputElm.length > 0) {
          inputElm = inputElm.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join("-");
        }
        elem.val(inputElm);
      });
    }
  };
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.search = function(element) {
    console.log(element);
    alert("keypressed. Value so far is: " + element.val());
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="TestApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input-format/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/anandgh/6unogzyh/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much sir. The code is working so perfectly.